# How to specify different path to build.properties for Ant?

Tags: java, ant

My build.properties is not in the same folder as build.xml. I know i could specify the path for build.properties with a param -Dsometing

Any idea what is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the output of `ant --help`. The option you are looking for is `-propertyfile`.

Exemple of usage:

```
ant -propertyfile subfolder/build.properties
```